# How to filter Large amount of data based upon Array Results - excel

Tags: arrays, if-statement, filter, excel-formula, large-data

I am trying to filter a very large amount of data (Almost 50K rows) using the box & whisker plot methods to help point out any outliers. I can't use the actual plotting method because the data is too large to I've been calculating w/ arrays.

My initial data is lake temp vs generation.

*****Raw Data (TABLE 1)*****
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCRCB.png)

I rounded Lake temp to a decimal point of 1, and made a second chart w/ temps ranging from 30-85 (increments of 0.1). For this second chart I used array formulas to calculate Min, 1st quartile, medium, 3rd quartile, and Max of the generation in table 1 for each respective temp.

ex: {=QUARTILE(IF(Data!$C$2:$C$49488=$A11,Data!$D$2:$D$49488),2)}

*****Calculated w/ Arrays (TABLE 2)*****
[Calculated Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAOR6.png)

Now I want to take the results from Table 2 and use that to filter out any outliers in table 1. Something like IF TABLE 2 temps = TABLE 1 temps, AND If Generation >= 1st quartile & <=3rd quartile for that specific temp, then "In Range", else "Out of Range".

My biggest issue is coming up with a formula that I can use to address the entire table 1 population without going through and sorting for each decimal point individually. I'm fairly new to arrays so trying to use arrays I've already made to build new arrays to filter upon old arrays is making my head spin. So far my online searching hasn't brought me any solutions beyond a simple array.

Thank you for your time.

I've also tried looking into For loops for a bit but vba but didn't get far... :(

Answer (score 1):

Attached/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9h55FVrb0lAg8r3S3Yg?e=ED6bHF) refer:

=FILTER(B15:B108,--(B15:B108<B7)*($B$15:$B$108>B6))

*(requires Excel 360 compatible version Excel)*

[image: Sample]